# Перевод названий знаков

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, знаки

Мне не нравятся переводы названий многих знаков. Часто выбрано первое попавшееся значение из англо-русского словаря, хотя оно может совсем не подходить к ситуации. Лучше основываться на смысле знака и не игнорировать контекст. Вот у меня конкретные предложения и темы для обсуждений:

1. **Outspoken/Искренний**: Опубликовать в чате 10 сообщений, которые были отмечены звездой 10 разными участниками. Апгрейд знака «Talkative/Общительный». Искренний тут вообще не подходит. Outspoken — это прямолинейный, открытый, который не скрывает мыслей и говорит, что думает. А в данном случае можно и отступить от оригинала и написать хоть «Разговорчивый», хоть просто «Чатер».
2. **Enlightened/Просвещённый**: Первым дал ответ, который был принят, с рейтингом 10 или более баллов. Может и неплохо, но название очень похоже на знак Illuminator/Просветитель. Предлагаю, например, «Знаток» — хорошее слово, ещё не занято.
3. **Mortarboard/Академик** + **Epic/Эпопея** + **Legendary/Легенда**. Три знака в цепочке, поэтому обсуждаем вместе. К легенде претензий нет, нормально. Эпопея — совершенно мимо кассы, это либо художественное произведение, либо длинная история. В английском epic — это прилагательное «эпичный», то есть типа герой эпоса. «Legendary», кстати, тоже в том же ряду — легендарный (то есть герой легенды). Но по-русски «легенда» как раз хорошо, так и про героя можно сказать. Epic можно перевести как «Герой» (тем более это слово пропало из Unsung hero/Непризнанный гений). Ещё вариант для Epic — «Звезда» (как на Хабре, у них там тоже Звезда/Легенда).

   Mortarboard — это чёрная квадратная шляпа, у выпускников и профессоров, ассоциирующаяся с клювом сокола. «Академик» без контекста подходило бы, но это ж бронзовый значок, а «Академик» — это должно быть более солидное звание. Вариант — всю цепочку переделать на «Кандидат», «Доктор» и «Академик» (чтобы Академик был золотым значком). Если не нравится, можно упростить только Академика (до «Выпускника» или «Аспиранта», не знаю).
4. **Convention/Делегат** — 10 сообщений на Мете с рейтингом 2 балла, апгрейд знака Quorum/Кворум. Перевод тоже мимо, convention — это собрание или съезд, как раз в контексте кворума. А делегат — это один человек. Есть много хороших слов взамен — «съезд», «собрание», «дума», «вече».
5. **Pundit/Учёный муж** — Оставить 10 комментариев, получивших минимум 5 баллов. — я не сильно против, но кажется, что «Эксперт» лучше. Если представить человека, который пишет полезные комментарии, то у меня в голове он со словом «эксперт» ассоциируется больше, чем с «учёным мужем».
6. **Citizen Patrol/Дружинник** + **Deputy/Помощник** + **Marshal/Пристав** — знаки за тревоги (flags). Приставы — это исполнители, их работа уже исполнить наказание (например, взыскать штраф), а не сообщить о преступлении, это другой конец правоохранительной цепочки. Тем более пристав — это не какая-то суперпочётная должность, которую надо заслужить, на золотой значок не тянет. Marshal — это в США судебный представитель, назначаемый президентом. Хоть немного близким по смыслу мне кажется «прокурор». Во всяком случае прокурор осуществляет надзор и может инициировать уголовные дела (по факту выдаёт flag, а потом следственные органы этот flag рассматривают). А deputy здесь — это конкретно помощник или заместитель этого самого маршала. По-русски «помощник» звучит слишком обще (в английском же не helper и не assistant). Можно опять же отойти от оригинала и написать «надзиратель» или «надсмотрщик». Цепочка «дружинник/надзиратель/прокурор» выглядит логичнее.
7. **Custodian/Страж** + **Reviewer/Инспектор** + **Steward/Завхоз** — знаки за задания по проверке. Мне одному кажется странной карьерная лестница от стража к инспектору, а потом к завхозу? Пусть завхоз будет хотя бы «Контролёром» (либо «контролёра» и «инспектора» переставить местами). Страж в принципе нормально, недлинно. Как вариант — можно заменить на «Блюстителя».

Comment: Согласен со всем, кроме, пожалуй, Quorum/Convention.Мне кажется, значок должен указывать на участника собрания, а не на само собрание. Кто-то предложит перевод получше?

Comment: оффтоп: mortarboard - он не про соколиный клюв, а про строительный инструмент - "сокол" - такой квадрат с ручкой снизу.

Comment: Enlightened/Знаток нравится, поддерживаю.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, *"mortarboard"* - "магистерская шапочка", называется так из-за сходства со строительным инструментом, эдакой дощечкой (*"board"*), на которой держат наносимую штукатурку/шпатлевку/раствор (*"mortar"*).

Comment: @Nofate: а, понял, спасибо. Действительно, логично.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, кругом вольные каменщики, в общем )

Comment: А ещё вручать знак "Учёный муж" женщине/девушке как-то странно)

Answer (score 7):

> **Citizen Patrol/Дружинник** + **Deputy/Участковый** + **Marshal/Прокурор**

Чтобы поддержать логику, для **Deputy** предлагаю перевод **Участковый**.

Comment: Поскольку по поводу этого перевода разночтений нету, внёс в transifex.

Answer (score 7):

**<s>Евангелист</s> *Толкователь* → Наставник → Просветитель**
**Explainer → Refiner → Illuminator**
(1/50/500 правок в паре с ответом.)

Опять какое-то странное творчество. Евангелист — это пафосное понятие, подразумевает ярых проповедников разных идей. Действия "один раз ответил и исправил вопрос" на евангелиста ни в одном приближении не тянут.

Слово "**объяснитель**" (или "**разъяснитель**") — не самое популярное в русском языке, но оно существует и отражает суть.

Если тянет на пафос и слова с налётом архаичности, можно воспользоваться словом "**толкователь**". Оно, конечно, опошлено "толкователями снов" и прочей мерзостью, но изначальное значение вполне подходит.

В компании с "наставником" и "просветителем" гармонично будет смотреться "толкователь", по-моему.

Comment: Толкователь неплох!

Answer (score 7):

**Хороший ответ → Отличный ответ → <s>Лучший</s> *Замечательный* ответ**
**Nice answer → Good answer → Great answer**
(Ответ на 10/25/100 баллов.)

"Хороший" и "Отличный" — это *абсолютные* оценки, они верны в отрыве от оценок на остальные ответы. "Лучший" — это *относительная* оценка, она существует только в сравнении с оценками на остальные ответы. Если оценки "–10" и "–20", то "–10" — лучший. Если оценки "120" и "130" — лучший только "130". То есть название знака *лжёт*.

Необходимо слово, которое дают абсолютную оценку и находится на ступеньку выше "отличный". По-моему, "**замечательный**" на эту роль вполне подходит.

P. S. Нужно поправить описание знака на 25 баллов.

Comment: Как вариант- великолепный ответ.

Comment: @NickVolynkin этот ответ можно считать утверждённым сообществом?

Comment: @alexolut а сейчас не этот вариант используется?

Comment: @NickVolynkin [не похоже](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/25/great-answer). Ну и симметрично надо с вопросами решить.

Comment: @alexolut действительно. Думаю, что перевод просто *замечательный*, можно его использовать. :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin мне на самом деле Ваш вариант, "великолепный", нравится больше. Но ещё больше понравился бы вариант "прекрасный" :)

Comment: "Великолепный" и "прекрасный" ещё и короче. Учитывая вёрстку, в которой любят задавать размеры пикселями, длинные названия могут выйти боком.

Answer (score 7):

**Энтузиаст → <s>Фанат</s> *Фанатик***
**Enthusiast → Fanatic**
(Посещение сайта 30/100 дней подряд.)

Не надо подслащать изначальное значение. Если бы в оригинале имели в виду "фанатов", то написали бы "fan". Там же ясно и чётко: "fanatic". Это слово описывает людей, которые не совсем в себе и на чём-то до одури помешаны, других значений у него нет. В данном случае — на Stack Overflow. И посещение сайта каждый день 100 дней подряд — отличное тому доказательство. Посетив сайт 100 дней подряд, вы доказываете, что вы не "поклонник" СО, а "**фанатик**" СО. Проявите уважение к оригинальному названию и улыбнитесь вместо того, чтобы прятать свою фанатичность от людских глаз. `;-)`

Comment: Поскольку по поводу этого перевода разночтений нету, внёс в transifex.

Answer (score 6):

**<s>Соревнование</s> *Спортивное поведение***
**Sportsmanship**
(Голосование за ответы конкурентов.)

Sportsmanship — это не когда человек даёт фору всем противникам от нечего делать, только чтобы сделать "соревнование" интереснее, а когда проявляет благородное **спортивное поведение**: проявляет уважение к соперникам, помогает им в случае проблем, признаёт их результаты и достижения.

В переводе на СО это означает, что нужно не минусовать конкурирующие вопросы и даже не плюсовать все подряд ради забавы, а что нужно плюсовать ответы, которые ты заплюсовал бы, если бы рядом не было твоего собственного. Это в первую очередь честность и благородство, а не догонялки.

Comment: Очень характеризует действие, за которое даётся значок

Comment: Поскольку по поводу этого перевода разночтений нету, внёс в transifex.

Answer (score 5):

**Mortarboard/Чемпион** + **Epic/Герой** + **Legendary/Легенда.**

Как мне кажется, здесь больше речь не об уровне знаний, а об известности. Посмотрите на [список обладателей этого знака на En.SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/146?page=4) — это же один в один список легендарных участников!

Comment: Если обсуждать в контексте известности, как насчет Mortarboard - Звезда?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: думаю, «звезда» — это «из другой оперы». Вызывает некоторые ассоциации со звездами кино, сцены и т.п. Там всё-таки другой источник известности — не дела или мастерство, а привлекательность и эмоции.

Comment: Тогда предлагаю ваш же вариант – «мастер».

Comment: Мне всё равно, "чемпион" это будет или "мастер", но в целом цепочка выглядит логично и гармонично. На мой взгляд, в значение "мастер" начали просачиваться восточные мотивы, поэтому я бы ограничился нейтральным "чемпионом" или даже чем-нибудь ещё проще.

Answer (score 5):

> **Convention/Активист**, **Quorum/Депутат**

По **Convention** - поддержу предложение @VladD. Лучше, если это будет слово, обозначающее отдельного человека. Мой вариант: **Convention/Активист**, **Quorum/Депутат**. Мне кажется, это вполне выражает род деятельности на Мете.

Comment: Хорошая комбинация, кстати!

Answer (score 5):

**<s>Сыщик</s> <s>*Землекоп*</s> *Копатель* → Археолог**
**Excavator → Archaeologiost**
(Ответы на старые вопросы.)

Сыщик — это когда нужно что-то найти, соответствующее вполне понятным критериям. Такой знак можно было бы давать за закрытие вопросов как дубликатов, например. А вот когда человек откопал где-то в дальних закоулках сайта старый вопрос и решил на него ответить, то он "**землекоп**". А если подобными раскопками он занимается постоянно, но он — "археолог". Археолог вырастает из землекопа, но где ж это видано, чтобы археолог вырастал из сыщика?

Comment: Тогда уж, не землекоп, а *копатель* (они в  одной смысловой  цепочке -- вполне логичен рост до археолога)

Comment: @avp Не заметил словарей, где было бы зафиксировано это значение, но кое-где в гугле натыкаюсь на значение "кладоискатель". Вы это имели в виду? Если да, то "копатель" лучше подходит, согласен.

Comment: Конечно, копатель это кладоискатель, хотя чаще они специализируются на "остатках войны".

Answer (score 4):

**Custodian/Инспектор** + **Reviewer/Страж** + **Steward/Судья**

Логичные имена для тех, кто разбирает <s>флаги</s> тревоги и вершит над ними суд, отделяя полезные тревоги от спорных, а хорошие сообщения от плохих.

Мне кажется, что «Страж» звучит более серьёзно и солидно, чем «Инспектор», поэтому такой порядок.

«Судья» хорошо сочетается с «Прокурором». Первый проверил сотни тревог, поднятых вторым. Сравните обе ветки попарно ([использую вариант от @VladD](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1261/1270#comment3502_1265)):

- Инспектор — Дружинник
- Страж — Участковый
- Судья — Прокурор

Answer (score 4):

**<s>Замеченный</s> *Популярный* вопрос → Известный вопрос → Знаменитый вопрос**
**Popular question → Notable question → Famous question**
(Вопрос с 1000/2500/10000 просмотров.)

Какой глубокий философский смысл менять слово "популярный" на "замеченный" — мне не понять. Замеченный вопрос — это если кто-то прошёл мимо и комментарий оставил. Тысяча просмотров — это уже популярность.

Ах да, описания знаков имеют разную формулировку, надо привести к единообразию.

Answer (score 4):

**Хороший ответ → Отличный ответ → <s>Лучший</s> *Великолепный* ответ**
**Nice answer → Good answer → Great answer**
(Ответ на 10/25/100 баллов.)

[Давно предложил](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1261/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2?cb=1#comment4533_1590), но не оформил как ответ. Исправляюсь. Логика та же, что и у Discord: абсолютная оценка вопроса вместо относительной/сравнительной.

Answer (score 3):

**<s>Скрытый талант</s> *Упорный* → Непризнанный гений**
**Tenacious → Unsung hero**
(За принятые ответы с оценкой 0.)

Знак подразумевает, что автор ответов твёрдо стоит на своём и продолжает отвечать, хотя не получает должной отдачи. Ему не нужны почести, он готов терпеть пренебрежение остальными ради своей цели.

А теперь скажите мне: при чём здесь "скрытый талант"? Какой талант? Почему он скрытый? Смысла в названии — ноль без палочки.

На ум приходят два слова: "**упёртый**" и "**упорный**". Первое с негативным оттенком и подразумевает, что пора бы уже сдаться и согласиться на уговоры. Второе — с положительным: не сдаваться, несмотря на все невзгоды. Так как знак положительный, то я предлагаю воспользоваться вторым словом. Как вариант, можно "**настойчивый**", "**неотступный**" или "**неуклонный**" какой-нибудь. Варианты более-менее равнозначны.

Я б ещё возразил по поводу "гения", ну да ладно, шут с ним.

Answer (score 2):

> **Custodian/Смотритель** + **Reviewer/Проверяющий** + **Steward/Хранитель**

ПО **Custodian/Reviewer/Steward**.
Steward - это в средние века - наместник, назначенный официальным правителем. Завхоз - действительно не то. **Custodian** - это либо смотритель (как в музее), либо что-то вроде нашего дореволюционного дворника: уборщик, охранник и ремонтник в одном лице, то есть тот кто смотрит за порядком в широком смысле. Для всей цепочки я бы предложил что-то вроде **Custodian/Смотритель** + **Reviewer/Проверяющий** + **Steward/Хранитель**. Получается "мирная" параллель "силовой" ветке **Citizen Patrol/Дружинник** + **Deputy/Участковый** + **Marshal/Прокурор**.

Comment: Если «дружинник» и «участковый», то может тогда и правда лучше «прокурор»? Пристав — это из другой реальности.

Comment: А вариант с Активист/Депутат поддерживаю.

Comment: Активист/Депутат можно, соглашусь. И поддержу @VladD, «дружинник/участковый/прокурор» нормально.

Comment: "Прокурора" поддерживаю

Comment: "Custodian - это либо смотритель (как в музее), либо что-то вроде нашего дореволюционного дворника: уборщик, охранник и ремонтник в одном лице, то есть тот кто смотрит за порядком в широком смысле" - сюда просится "вахтёр"

Comment: @insolor: «вахтёр» у меня вызывает ассоциации с «синдромом вахтёра». Надеюсь, что этот недуг не поразит обладателей знака.

Answer (score 0):

**<s>Альтруист</s> *Меценат***
**Altruist**
(Вручил награду за ответ на **чужой** вопрос.)

*Меценат* — лицо, способствующее на добровольной и безвозмездной основе развитию науки и искусства, оказывающее им материальную помощь из личных средств.

*Альтруизм* — понятие, которым осмысливается активность, связанная с бескорыстной заботой о благополучии других; соотносится с понятием самоотверженность — то есть с приношением в жертву своих выгод в пользу блага другого человека, других людей или в целом — ради общего блага. В некоторых смыслах может рассматриваться как противоположное эгоизму.

В целом оба значения подходят, но может быть, чуть точнее выражает суть слово меценат.

Comment: Вообще-то в понятие меценатов включаются и те, кто заказывает арт за бабки и кто таким образом достигает каких-то иных целей, вполне рациональных. В целом это все, на бабки кого существуют творческие люди, безотносительно мотивации. Если приводите цитату из Википедии, то до конца статьи дочитали бы что ли. :) А вот альтруист — это как раз "сделать другому хорошо, забив на свои интересы", без всяких вариантов с выгодой. В целом я против коверкания оригинала.

Comment: @Discord спасибо за разъяснения, действительно, был недостаточно внимателен

Answer (score 0):

**<s>Благодетель</s> *Благодарный***
**Benefactor**
(Вручил награду за ответ на **свой** вопрос.)

Вот здесь я думаю, изменение названия даёт гораздо больше понимания того, за что даётся значок.

Благодетель как-то не ассоциируется с тем, кто награждает за то, что ему помогли. Скорее всё же он благодарный.

Comment: Предполагается, что помощь щедрая, то есть что это не работа за минимальную оплату, а щедрый дар в благодарность за помощь. Так как в оригинале "benefactor", то есть "благодетель", "благотворитель", "меценат", то я бы не коверкал оригинал и не фантазировал что-то своё. Ну и звучит "благодарный" уныло на фоне остальных значков. :)

Answer (score 0):

Цепочка
**Любознательный -> <s>Пытливый ум</s> *Дотошный* -> Сократ**
**Curious -> Inquisitive -> Socratic**
(За большое (5, 30, 100) количество интересных вопросов в разные дни.)

Думаю, дотошный чуть более точно выражает становление этого значка, а заодно и выставляет их в примерно ровную цепь. Пытливый ум немного выбивается из ряда в этом плане.

Comment: Плюсую, "дотошный" хорошо вписывается в цепочку.

Answer (score 0):

@TimofeyBondarev поднял вопрос меценатства и альтруизма, поэтому решил обратить внимание на награды за <s>райское наслаждение</s> баунти.

**<s>Инвестор</s> *Вкладчик*** / **Investor** / Объявление награды за ответ на чужой вопрос
**Альтруист** / **Altruist** / Выдача награды за ответ на чужой вопрос
**<s>Промоутер</s> *Патрон*** / **Promoter** / Объявление награды за ответ на свой вопрос
**<s>Благодетель</s> *Меценат*** / **Benefactor** / Выдача награды за ответ на свой вопрос

"**Альтруист**" вариантов перевода не имеет, поэтому обсуждению не подлежит.

"Инвестор" имеет русский вариант "**вкладчик**". Если среди нас преобладают славянофилы, то можно изменить. Меня в данном случае можете считать славянофилом.

Меня несколько напрягает, что "альтруист" и "вкладчик" не образуют нормальную цепочку, даже наоборот: это практически антонимы. Поэтому, если кто-то предложит слабую версию альтруизма, то я буду не против. Хоть это и идёт вразрез с идеей не коверкать оригинал.

В случае "промоутера" уже сильные подозрения на промах: попахивает ложным другом переводчика. Если в русском языке это слово означает вполне конкретную профессию, то в английском [диапазон значений гораздо шире](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?s=promoter): "**покровитель**", "**патрон**", "импрессарио", "организатор", "учредитель", "сторонник"... "Промоутер" где-то в конце этого списка с пометой "рекл."

У слова "benefactor" [значения в том же ключе](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?s=benefactor), но их меньше: "**благодетель**", "**благотворитель**", "**благожелатель**", "**жертвователь**", "**меценат**".

Так как знак "promoter" должен быть слабой версией знака "benefactor", то "покровитель" звучит слишком пафосно, а вот "**патрон**" — уже нормально. В свете популярности платформы Patreon, проблем с распознаванием этого слова быть не должно. Тогда для "benefactor" логично выбрать "**меценат**", и слова выстроятся в логичную цепочку.

Comment: Promoter подразумевает не столько сам факт объявления награды, сколько цель награды - привлечь внимание к вопросу, продвинуть, разрекламировать его. Перевод "Меценат" не соответствует сути этого действия. А вот парный знак, Benefactor, подразумевает что рекламировать уже нечего, и пользователь просто от всей души выдает награду другому пользователю. К тому же,  "патрон" и "меценат" - синонимы (хотя "меценат" подразумевает богатого покровителя наук и искусств, в то время как "патрон" - просто покровителя)

Comment: @PashaPash Вы утверждаете про рекламное значение "promoter" с такой уверенностью, как будто вы носитель языка. Пока что я смотрю в словари и не вижу, что это значение основное. Хочу мнение носителя. / В общем-то, в этом и идея, чтобы сделать слабую и сильную версию одного и того же, потому что значки идут друг за другом.

Comment: я не утверждаю, что это основное значение. я предлагаю выбрать название, соответствующее действию - назначению награды с целью *привлечь внимание* к вопросу. И я не считаю, что эти значки действительно представляют собой слабую/сильную версию одного знака -  получить "сильную" версию должно быть на порядок сложнее, чем "слабую" (как в случае с энтузиаст -> фанатик, например). Это просто связанные знаки, а не слабая и сильная версии одного и того же знака. они даже на [списке знаков](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) не сгруппированы, в отличие от остальных "знаков-уровней"

Answer (score -1):

**<s>Промоутер</s> *Пропагандист***
**Promoter**
(Предлагает награду за свой вопрос)

Думаю, промоутер может не так понятно звучать.

Думаю над вариантами, относящимися к рекламе и продаже, но ничего адекватного в голову не пришло. Но по сути здесь участник как раз "рекламирует" свой вопрос, используя вознаграждение.

Есть ещё мысль назвать "наёмщик", но звучит немного не в тему SO.

Comment: Я бы держался от пропаганды подальше, нынче это актуальное слово с острым политическим окрасом. Да и в целом оно негативное. И у вас неправильный словарь. Вот [правильный](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?s=promoter).

Answer (score -3):

1. Не болтай!
2. Просветленный
3. Легендарный => Эпический => Мифический
4. Депутат
5. Тонкий
6. Стукач => Доносчик => Кровавая гэбня
7. Дворник => Вахтёр => Завхоз

Комбинации радуют:

1. Просветленный мифический депутат
2. Тонкий стукач дворник
3. Эпический завхоз, Не болтай!

Comment: «Просветлённый» — хорошо, а тонкий стукач дворник порвал фкуски :)

Comment: А если ваще по фене?

Comment: Да какая разница какой сеттинг отыгрывать. Хотя знак "Смотрящий по камере" забавно бы смотрелся.

Comment: Толстые эпические депутаты-минусаторы отклонили мой инновационный проект по переименованию улицы, какая жалость.

Comment: @igumnov: ничего, пригодится, когда откроется тюряга.stackoverflow.com =)

Comment: @Nick шконкаoverflow.com я бы даже сказал.

Comment: @igumnov зэкoverflow.com

Comment: @NickVolynkin, зонаexchange.com