# Переименование знака «Евангелист»

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, знаки

> Отредактировать 1 вопрос и ответить на 1 вопрос (оба действия в течение 12 часов, рейтинг за ответы > 0).

(*Из чата*)

Почему значок с этим описанием называется [«Евангелист»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/90/explainer), чем руководствовался придумавший название? Что может быть общего между [евангелистами](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc_bible/1290/%D0%95%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82) и пользователем, выполнившим условия для получения данного знака? Причём это не калька с английской версии Stack Overflow, там знак называется [«Explainer»](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4368/explainer) — «человек, который объясняет».

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Евангелистом также называют человека, который популяризирует любое знание, технологию, метод. Как [уже писал однажды Discord](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1589/181472):

> Евангелист — это пафосное понятие, подразумевает ярых проповедников разных идей. Действия "один раз ответил и исправил вопрос" на евангелиста ни в одном приближении не тянут.

Там же предлагается решение:

**<s>Евангелист</s> *Толкователь* → Наставник → Просветитель**
**Explainer → Refiner → Illuminator**
(1/50/500 правок в паре с ответом.)

Поскольку в давнем голосовании этот вариант уже получил поддержку, я его [только что применил](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40262387?key=5d36a5465a09a0e60df0debc972260f9). Ждите в следующем обновлении.

Comment: Евангелиста можно было бы давать за ситуацию, когда у участника за одну метку есть золотой знак, а больше знаков за метки нет.