# Почему завхоза превратили в мажордома?

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, знаки

Знак [Steward](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/83/steward) раньше был переведен как "Завхоз", а теперь - "Мажордом". Чем вызвано данное изменение?

Comment: Хм.. Я даже такого слова не знаю о_О

Comment: Вот что бывает, когда до переводов добираются модераторы с русского языка :D

Comment: @Qwertiy Вроде такой хостинг был

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan кажется, он назывался «Мажордомо». Мне всегда было интересно, с чем связано это название.

Comment: Жутчайшее название! Хотел бы я знать кто его так переименовал?! Верните завхоза!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

В контексте *значения* (*Выполнить минимум 1000 заданий по проверкам.*) я бы предложил **Ревизор** или **Контролер** :)

Вписывается в ряд с *Инспектором* и *Смотрителем*.

Но *Мажордом* - простите, но по мне - ни в какие ворота... Еще хуже, чем *Завхоз*.

Comment: Отличное предложение! Ревизор – в точку.

Comment: "Ревизор" идеально, как мне кажется.

Comment: Эм, почему два предложения в одном посте? Как понять - мне плюсануть за один или минус влепить за другой?

Comment: Я предлагаю к обсуждению, а не к голосованию :)

Comment: @Aid А вы в комментариях голосуйте или создайте новый ответ:)

Comment: Не хочу :).....

Comment: @Aer Переименуете в "Ревизора"?

Comment: плюс за ревизора

Answer (score 11):

**UPD:** по итогам голосования было принято решение переименовать знак, используя название «Ревизор».

---

Этот перевод был предложен мной, но сейчас не является принятым:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Непонятно, почему именно он отображается на сайте.

---

Просматривая не переведённые строки, я наткнулся на название этого знака. (Удивительно, но многие строки, которые де-факто переведены, в Transifex отображаются как не переведённые.)

Выбирая подходящий перевод, я старался подобрать такое слово, которое было бы созвучным другим названиям знаков за проверки: [смотритель](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c) и [инспектор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80). Они объединены общим значением 'человек, проверяющий что-либо, следящий за порядком' и оба имеют довольно длинную историю, тогда как «завхоз» обычно является лицом, управляющим хозяйственной стороной предприятия: он занимается наймом подрядчиков, осматривает помещения, принимает решение о ремонте и т. д. — а также представляет собой профессию, появившуюся значительно позже, нежели две предыдущие.

Мажордом — должность, которая хронологически лучше вписывается в ряд [смотритель](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c), [инспектор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80), но всё равно слишком косвенно соотносится с [семой](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0) 'человек, проверяющий что-либо, следящий за порядком'. Думаю, можно придумать перевод получше — например, *хранитель*. Буду рад любым советам!

Более того, значение слова *steward* (someone who helps to organize something) едва ли можно с лёгкостью перевести на русский. Кажется, что именно такой смысл вкладывали разработчики, когда вводили этот знак: человек, который следит за сайтом и его благосостоянием.

Если у вас остались вопросы или предложения, пожалуйста, опишите их в комментариях.

Comment: " Более того, значение слова steward (someone who helps to organize something) едва ли можно с легкостью перевести на русский."

Тамада же :-)

Comment: Почему не оставить (только русскими буквами) [стюард](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%8E%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B4_(%D1%84%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB))?

Comment: @Uranus, тамада не очень. Ассоциируется с тостами на торжестве.

Comment: @avp, угу, это была шутка. К тому же я немного самопросветился, и обнаружил что у меня и ассоциация некорректно сработала. :-)

Comment: @avp это слово в значении, на которое вы ссылаетесь, появилось в русском языке значительно позже, нежели _смотритель_ и _инспектор_. Хотелось бы найти нечто более созвучное.

Comment: @Aer, это в футболе. А аналог стюардессы на флоте давным-давно присутствует в литературе (в принципе, с теми же функциями)

Comment: @avp в начале XX века стюард — корабельный слуга, мальчик на побегушках, грубо говоря. В футболе же он имеет чуть большую важность. Но в целом ваше предложение хорошее, спасибо.

Comment: Зачем вообще надо было менять перевод? Я понимаю, что он «слетел» в Transifex, но на сайте ведь не слетал. К тому же в Transifex есть список предложений, где видно прежние варианты.

Comment: @alexolut о причинах я написал в своем ответе. Я увидел диссонанс и попытался его устранить.

Comment: Диссонанс имеет смысл устранять коллегиально, особенно устоявшийся диссонанс. Вот, например, [тема](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1261/176217) как раз о знаках. Люди собирались, обсуждали, а не устраивали локализаторский произвол.

Comment: @alexolut кажется, мною всего лишь было внесено предложение, и позже я хотел создать соответствующий вопрос; видимо, либо случайно применил это изменение, либо произошла ошибка — в любом случае я бы не стал называть мой перевод локализаторским произволом. В вопросе, на который вы сослались, предложен перевод, который так и не был применен.

Comment: @Aer Я за то, чтобы вернули как было. Название было намного привычней и понятней. Слово все понимали, а не было экзотикой. Да и по значению, как мне кажется, подходит.

Comment: Воу, разве целью языка не является помощь в осознании свойств идентифицируемого объекта, а потеря ясности в угоду непонятной большинство точности? Т. е. я понимаю что "Мажордом" может точнее по смыслу, но сильно хуже в определении предназначения знака.

Comment: Смотритель тоже раньше назывался по другому - "Страж". "Завхоз", на мой взгляд, лучше вписывался в линию со стражем и инспектором, "Мажордом" выглядит слишком изысканно. "Хранитель", несомненно, нравится больше.

Comment: Учитывая то, что первый знак из линейки даётся за **одну** проверку, там должно быть что-то максимально непафосное/обыденное (но при этом не унизительное). Возможно, стоит зайти с другой стороны, устоявшиеся два термина переместить на серебро/золото, а бронзу пересмотреть.

Comment: @Aid надо было бы поточнее и попонятнее, поэтому я и сделал лишь предложение. Надеюсь, вместе мы сможем выбрать наиболее подходящий вариант: проголосуйте под ответом ниже.

Comment: `UPD: по итогам голосования было принято решение переименовать знак, используя название «Ревизор»` — сейчас знак снова называется  «Завхоз». Ошибка применения перевода или так задумано (временно)?

Comment: @Arhad при следующей подгрузке переводов все будет как надо.

Answer (score 8):

Если вы считаете, что нужно изменить перевод на «Хранитель», проголосуйте за.

Answer (score 6):

Если вы считаете, что нужно оставить «Завхоза», проголосуйте за.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы считаете, что нужно изменить перевод на «Стюард», проголосуйте за.

Answer (score 0):

Проголосуйте за, если, на ваш взгляд, стоит пересмотреть все три названия знаков за проверки.