# Переименовать "Лучший вопрос/ответ"

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, знаки

В [старинной теме](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1261/176217) перевода названия знаков присутствовали варианты:

- [Великолепный](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1628/176217)
- [Замечательный](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1590/176217)

Однако, почему-то в текущей интерпретации соответствующие знаки за [вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/22/great-question) и [ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/25/great-answer) содержат слово **"Лучший"**. В данном случае, это слово не совсем уместно, т.к. "лучший" предполагает лучше всех, то есть один единственный, но как мы видим, таких сообщений может быть несколько. "Лучший"   уместно использовать в контексте ответа с галочкой, т.к. она может быть только одна, хотя бывали и [прецеденты](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316568/339911) иного вида. Но для знаков, которые могут присваиваться во множественном числе нужна иная характеристика, чем "Лучший".

Дополнительно предлагаю рассмотреть вариант [Прекрасный](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1261/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2#comment16142_1590). Пожалуйста, высказывайтесь за те или иные варианты, предлагайте свои, или расскажите, почему на ваш взгляд перевод менять не стоит.

В оригинале цепочка прилагательных по знакам выглядит так:

> **Nice → Good → Great**

Пока что это выглядит как:

> **Хороший → Отличный → Лучший**

Comment: Замечательный +1!

Comment: Nice → Good - вообще странная градация, т.к.это одно и тоже.

Comment: @Suvitruf не одно и то же. В разных контекстах, имеет разное значение. Nice - быстрее "отличный", а Good - "хороший". Хороший и отличный ведь имеют уже разницу на русском? Это как 4+ и 5

Comment: @VladSpirin в контексте описания объектов [считают одинаковыми](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/26170).

Comment: @älёxölüt я ж и написал про контекст, но как раз тут вопрос не про объекты. Хотя...., может и объекты, мир то объектный......,аааааааааааа, ........ ООП

Comment: @VladSpirin объекты, в плане не живые люди. Вопросы/ответы как раз к таким относятся.

Comment: Будет думаю лучше `Превосходный` так сказать превосходящий все другие :)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб а если перевод не применится?

Comment: @älёxölüt, ну, тогда тут, наверное, появится тревога соответствующая... =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На основании голосов в комментариях и в том числе старого голосования на Мете выбран **замечательный** вариант.

> Замечательный вопрос
>
> Замечательный ответ

Будет на сайте после обновления Transifex и пересборки движка.