# Только лишь "лучшие ответы получают голоса и поднимаются наверх"?

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, анонимный-пользователь

Если зайти анонимным юзером, то показывается плашка:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Только лишь "лучшие" получают голоса или "хорошие" тоже? Было похожее обсуждение: [Переименовать "Лучший вопрос/ответ"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8170/15479).

Может тут тоже поменяем текст?

Comment: Ну по идее же в топ попадают лучшие, а не хорошие? Впрочем, при том, что у нас обычно не так уж много ответов... С другой стороны, на безрыбье и рак - рыба, т. е. если есть один ответ, то он лучший (среди одного), но не обязательно хороший :D

Comment: @Qwertiy голоса получают хорошие ответы, а не только лучшие.

Comment: Получают - хорошие (хотя минус - тоже голос, так что вообще все), а наверх всплывают лучшие. По крайней мере я так понимаю.

Comment: А вот обратный пример - вопросу много лет, и тема вопроса со времени публикации эволюционировала, и появились ответы учитывающие эволюцию темы вопроса. Скорее всего, в таком вопросе "топ" будет тот вопрос, который самый первый раз ответил на поставленный вопрос, а те ответы, что стали учитывать эволюцию, так и останутся ниже, особенно если эволюционных итераций было много... Вот пример такого вопроса, пусть и с англоязычного ресурса https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285917/how-to-disable-javascript-when-using-selenium?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @AtachiShadow исключения есть во всём )

Comment: Поэтому, лично моё мнение, надпись "Хорошие ответы получают голоса" будет ближе к истине, хотя тоже не идеал))

Comment: А предложение "Замечательный" как в предложенном голосовании, мне кажется тоже не подходит, ведь "Замечательный" по своему смыслу это превосходная форма "Хороший", и как я понимаю, суть предложения в большей размытости термина, что-бы больше Ответов попадали под категорию тех, кто получает Голоса)) А со словом "Замечательный" обратная ситуация, смысл - "Исключительно хороший". То есть, как по мне, в область такого термина попадают ещё меньше ответов, чем по "Лучший"

Answer (score 2):

Отдаю голос за "Хорошие ответы получают голоса и поднимаются наверх".

Ответы могут быть не "Лучшими". На вопрос могут ответить несколько человек, и все они будут с голосами и сверху, так как рассмотрят, к примеру, разные аспекты и автору вопроса и сообществу понравятся сразу несколько.

Ответы со сравнительно максимальными голосами могут быть инертными (больше голосов => больше внимания пользователей => больше голосов), и тогда ответ может быть "Лучшим" по количеству голосов, а не по содержанию.

И конечно же, в смысловую категорию "Хороший" попадает большее количество ответов, чем в категорию "Лучший". А значит смысл таков:

Ответ должен содержать информацию достаточную для решения проблемы вопросителя. И это совсем не значит, что отвечающий должен будет 7 потов выбить из себя, что-бы получить ну хоть один голос "за". Бывают ситуации, когда сообщество и вопроситель будут благодарны даже за частичное решение проблемы.